# How to enforce component service interface in angular

Tags: angular

I would like to design a component where I want to enforce.
Notice the constructor.

```js
//cool-header.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'cool-header',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CoolHeader {
   constructor(private userService: UserService) {};

   getUser(): User {
      return this.userService.getUser();
   }
}
```

Further down I would like UserService to be interface

```js
//user.ts
export interface UserService {
    getUser(): User;
}
```

Now the users of my components should use the components as follows:

```js
//demo.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app-root',
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: `<cool-header></cool-header>`,
  providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}]
})
export class DemoComponent {

}
```

Notice `providers` - this is saying that this component provides a concrete  implementation of `UserService` interface with `MockUserService`.

But I am not able to this due to 2 main issues.
In `DemoComponent` I get Error and `CoolHeader` I get

> ```js
> Can't resolve all parameters for CoolHeader: (?).
> ```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies ---> "TypeScript interfaces aren't valid tokens"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies) :

> #### TypeScript interfaces aren't valid tokens
>
> (...)
>
> That seems strange if you're used to dependency injection in strongly
>   typed languages, where an interface is the preferred dependency lookup
>   key.
>
> It's not Angular's doing. An interface is a TypeScript design-time
>   artifact. JavaScript doesn't have interfaces. The TypeScript interface
>   disappears from the generated JavaScript. There is no interface type
>   information left for Angular to find at runtime.

As **interfaces do not exist in JS**, you need to use that workaround :

1. Create an injection token (in `user.ts`):

   ```js
   export let USER_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<UserService>('my-user-service');
   ```
2. in your `demo.component.ts` :

   ```js
   providers: [{ provide: USER_SERVICE, useClass: MockUserService }]
   ```
3. and in `cool-header.component.ts`:

   ```js
   constructor( @Inject(USER_SERVICE) private userService: UserService) {};
   ```

Comment: I am assuming we create injection token in cool-header.component.ts ?

Comment: I would rather do that in user service as this is the token that defines the service for injector.